# How to recover blockchain wallet on iPhone with address & PIN?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

My iPhone crashed and I lost access to blockchain app. I have my savings in that wallet which I can't access anymore. Is there anyway I can recover my previous wallet?

I have the transaction history and the address I also have 4 digit PIN that I used at the time (nothing other then that). Please help I want to get out of this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to spend coins (aka recover them in your case) without having the private keys. You do not have enough information to have the private keys (address is not enough, 4 digit PIN is only for unlocking the wallet). Thus your coins may be lost.

However, blockchain.info is an online wallet. You should be able to go to their website and access your Bitcoin that way. You will need to have the account identifier (or wallet identfier, whatever it is called) and your password.